# IBOutlet is not being recognized as an UIImageView

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to allow users to take photos when the button action is clicked. I've added an UIImageView into storyboard which is to my View Controller. I've set the name for this control as imageView, yet when I implement imageView.image = image I am getting an error "Cannot find 'imageView' in scope". I've also tried to set this as self.imageView = image and I get the error "Cannot find self in scope". I am unsure why my imageView which is connected to the @IBOutlet is not being found?

```
    import UIKit

class HomeScreenViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
     @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
     var button: UIButton! {
         imageView.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        self.button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    @IBAction func didTapButton(){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any])      {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage  else {
        return
    }
    
    imageView.image = image
    
}
```

Comment: YOu forgot to put your functions inside your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not inside your class!! You should put the function inside the class, like this:

```
class HomeScreenViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]){
       // any code
    }
}
```

Comment: should I have it in both places or only inside of the class?

Comment: No, you should put it inside the class; otherwise, the function cannot access imageView.

Comment: @WenLoveHoward both functions should go only inside the class. Your `HomeScreenViewController` is the delegate, so it must contain them.